# Matching a single number to closest in range in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table showing grading figures based on numbers, like this:

- 0-24 = Newbie
- 25-49 = Trainee
- 50-74 = Moderate
- 75-99 = Pro
- 100 = Superman

I need to take a numeric value, and match it to the closest equivalent grade above.  So, **80** would equate to **Pro**, as it meets the base *Pro* level, but is lower than the base *Superman* level.

I have written some code to test this, but the TOP 1 filter seems to get applied before the JOIN, meaning that I always see the lowest grade instead of the actual grade.  Can anyone help me to suggest a better alternative?

[SQL Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/3393)

Code here:

```
DECLARE @tbl_levels TABLE ([schemeID] int, [calevel] numeric(5,2), [desc] nvarchar(200))
DECLARE @level numeric(5,2) = 70
DECLARE @schemeID int = 1

insert into @tbl_levels ([schemeID],[calevel],[desc]) VALUES (1, 0, 'Newbie')
insert into @tbl_levels ([schemeID],[calevel],[desc]) VALUES (1, 25, 'Trainee')
insert into @tbl_levels ([schemeID],[calevel],[desc]) VALUES (1, 50, 'Moderate')
insert into @tbl_levels ([schemeID],[calevel],[desc]) VALUES (1, 75, 'Pro')
insert into @tbl_levels ([schemeID],[calevel],[desc]) VALUES (1, 100, 'Superman')

SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT
        @level as [level],
        @schemeID as [schemeID]) ca LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        TOP 1 * 
    FROM 
        @tbl_levels
    ORDER BY 
        calevel ASC
    ) lvl ON lvl.schemeID = ca.schemeID AND lvl.calevel <= ca.[level]
```

Comment: Can you reorganise the levels table so that it has a start and end range, rather than just a starting level? This would enable you to make a simple join that included a `between` condition.

Comment: It would make the entering of this data pretty difficult and lots of validation would be needed on the client-side to prevent overlapping ranges.  I just posted a revision to my SQL Fiddle but don't think its loaded for some reason... http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/3413

Comment: On testing out the three different approaches, for 100,000 rows the queries averaged out at the following:  Mark Bannister 233ms, bummi 381ms, Remus Rusanu 346ms meaning that CTE is about 25% faster than the other approaches.  Does that seem true based on your experience?  Thanks!

Comment: It seems reasonable - not directly due to a CTE being used, but because the CTE approach means that the levels table only has to be accessed twice, while the correlated subquery approach means that it has to be accessed once for each row in the test data table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Updated) Try:

```
;with r as 
(select l.*, row_number() over (partition by [schemeID] order by [calevel]) rn
 from @tbl_levels l),
cte as
(select l.*, n.[calevel] as [nextlevel]
 from r l 
 left join r n on l.[schemeID] = n.[schemeID] and l.rn+1 = n.rn)
SELECT
    ca.*, cte.[calevel],cte.[nextlevel],cte.[desc]
FROM @test ca 
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte
ON ca.schemeID = cte.schemeID AND 
   ca.[level] >= cte.[calevel] AND
   ca.[level] < coalesce(cte.[nextlevel], ca.[level]+1)
```

(SQLFiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/3417))

Comment: Hi Mark.  Sorry just seen your post when I refreshed.  Could you please check out my amended SQL Fiddle as I actually need to apply the descriptive references across a large number of values?  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/3413

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks again.  Please excuse my ignorance but there is a *lot* of code here, and I am not very familiar with CTE's.  Could you break the logic down so I can follow it through?  I know @bummi has not yet revised his answer but his initial response was much shorter (not that I'm saying its any better of course - just hoping to understand your approach from a simplicity/efficiency perspective)

Comment: @EvilDr: The simplest way to determine which approach is best is to run both of them against the real data and find which produces the desired results and has the best performance.

Comment: Hi, yes I agree and appreciate that.  Would really welcome a narrative of how your logic works though :-)

Comment: @EvilDr: The first CTE (aliased `r`) simply adds a sequence number for each scheme to the levels table, ordered by level value. The second CTE (aliased as `cte`) then joins the first cte to itself on the same scheme and the *next* sequence number - esentially, this CTE dynamically mimics the structure of the levels table I suggested in my comment on your question. The final query then joins the test data to this CTE on scheme, and level value being between current start and next start value. (Coalesce handles the possibility that the current record is the highest, so there is no next value.)

Comment: Thanks.  Please feel free to comment on my result times posted as a comment in the original question.  This approach worked out the fastest but I would appreciate why it is better than APPLY?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT @level as Level,s.*
from @tbl_levels s
where [calevel]=(Select Max([calevel]) from @tbl_levels where [calevel]<=@level)
```

as answer to your comment

```
SELECT
    t.[level],
    (Select [desc] from @tbl_levels where [calevel]=(Select Max([calevel]) from @tbl_levels where [calevel]<=t.[level])) as [Desc]
FROM
    @test t
```

Comment: Thanks bummi.  In my actual work I have many thousands of leves/schemeIDs in a results table that I need to match.  Could you please show how that could be done?  I've created a fresh SQL Fiddle example which hopefully makes it more obvious.  Thanks. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/3413

Comment: Thanks.  Please feel free to comment on my result time posted as a comment in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

You can rephrase the question as "What is the highest level that matches a given value?" and then the solution becomes evident. Level 70 is 'Moderate':

```
SELECT TOP(1) @level, *
FROM @tbl_levels
WHERE [calevel] <= @level
ORDER BY calevel DESC;
```

For multiple value simply use [CROSS APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT
    t.[level],
    lvl.[desc]
FROM @test t 
cross apply (
select top(1) *
from @tbl_levels
where [calevel] <= [level]
order by calevel desc) as lvl;
```

Comment: Hi yes that's fine for a single value, but when I require a descriptive row matching many values that logic doesn't work (see my earlier replies).  Thanks.  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/3413

Comment: @EvilDr: whenever you want correlated joins, the answer will be an `APPLY`. See edit.

Comment: Thanks.  Please feel free to comment on my result times posted as a comment in the original question.

Comment: You need an index on `[calevel]`

Comment: Thanks. I created a non-clustered index on #temptable using schemeID & level, as #temp will eventually hold many hundreds of different grading schemes.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tbl_levels TABLE ([schemeID] int, [calevel] numeric(5,2), [desc] nvarchar(200))
DECLARE @level numeric(5,2) = 70
DECLARE @schemeID int = 1

insert into @tbl_levels ([schemeID],[calevel],[desc]) VALUES (1, 0, 'Newbie')
insert into @tbl_levels ([schemeID],[calevel],[desc]) VALUES (1, 25, 'Trainee')
insert into @tbl_levels ([schemeID],[calevel],[desc]) VALUES (1, 50, 'Moderate')
insert into @tbl_levels ([schemeID],[calevel],[desc]) VALUES (1, 75, 'Pro')
insert into @tbl_levels ([schemeID],[calevel],[desc]) VALUES (1, 100, 'Superman')

SELECT
    TOP 1 *
FROM
    (SELECT
        @level as [level],
        @schemeID as [schemeID]) ca LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT *
        FROM 
        @tbl_levels
    ) lvl ON lvl.schemeID = ca.schemeID AND lvl.calevel <= ca.[level]
    ORDER BY lvl.calevel DESC
```

Raj

Comment: Thanks for this, however there is another problem.  In my actual query level and schemeID are actually in a table with thousands of entries, so I need to match up the level and schemeID values a lot of times.  Can the TOP 1 filter therefore not be placed at the start of query?